# What do you call a team which it's players play in a very coordinated way?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

What do you call a team whose players play in a very coordinated way, and all know each other well (meaning that each player knows how the other teammate plays and plays according to the other player's playing in a manner that maximizes the team's performance) Short and to the point - they play in a very coordinated manner together.

Based on my own dictionary definitions, all the following terms should be correct, but I've found their meanings in some online dictionaries. So I doubt if they are correct now. Please help me to find the best choice which a native speaker would say:

> a) [coordinated](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/coordinate_1) team
>
> b) [coherent](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/coherent) team
>
> c) [harmonious](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/harmonious) team
>
> d) [homogeneous](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/homogeneous) team

Based on dictionary definitions, I guess there should be a fixed term. I'm looking for that; otherwise, these all can work properly, at least for me and according to the dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tight-knit)...

> **tight-knit** *- closely and firmly integrated*
>    [*a tight-knit team*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20tight-knit%20team%22) (that's over 900 hits in Google Books)

Note that plain ***tight*** is also quite common, particularly in reference to a *band* (group of musicians) whose playing is highly coordinated. In many contexts, *tight-knit* may also have strong overtones of *bound in love or friendship*, but that "emotional" dimension isn't *required* for the usage.

Comment: Wow. Great. So it is possible to call such a team a "tight-knit team". Thank you very much FumbleFingers. It was very informative. :)

Comment: @A-friend: I was adding just that example as you were writing your comment! So obviously the answer is *Yes, indeed!* Note that *homogeneous* means *all of the same type*, *harmonious* usually means *get on well together*, and *coherent* usually means *sensible, comprehensible*, so they're probably not the meanings you want anyway. And *coordinated* would usually be used more explicitly as ***well-coordinated***. In fact, *a well-coordinated team* is actually more common than *a tight-knit team* in Google Books, but I think the latter sounds more idiomatic today (especially in *speech*).

Answer (score 0):

From your description I would say that the members display precision teamwork, in that they always do exactly the thing needed to support the other team members. I might even say they display seamless coordination, in that there are no gaps left to be covered.  For a more common phrasing **well-coordinated** would be the most common phrasing.

Going through your dictionary-based suggestions:

> a) coordinated team

This doesn't feel like it's strong enough without an intensifier.

> b) coherent team

If someone was talking about a **coherent** team I'd think more of a business, where all members play a needed role in meeting the common goals.  (Often you hear stories about a business that fails because of an incoherent business strategy, where different goals are pursued that don't add up to a useful whole.)

> c) harmonious team

**harmonious** means "smooth and peaceful".  While a harmonious team may be quite capable of working together effectively, and a disharmonious team is unlikely to accomplish the same thing, a harmonious team is not necessarily an effective one.

> d) homogeneous team

**homogeneous** means "all the same".  You can say that a country's population is homogeneous when everyone speaks the same native language and there is very little or no evidence of ethnic minorities.  In the context of a sports team you might have a group of generalist players, with none specialized in a skill above the others.  In most sports this would not be a helpful thing.  (However, a youth sports coach might appreciate having a team that was all at the same approximate level of skill rather than having to balance a group of players with wildly divergent abilities.)